# View a windows format DVD on Mac

Tags: windows, dvd, dvd-burning

I have a DVD from my holiday a few years back in which I would like to place into my mac and view, and extract the video for my library. This is my only option. I was wondering if anyone knew how to view a DVD on a mac that has been formatted as a windows DVD? Whenever I insert it, I receive a message claiming that it's an empty disk, but I know it isn't. If anyone could help me that would be fantastic!

Comment: A ‘Windows’ DVD would be fine on macOS, so there must be something else with the DVD. How was the DVD burned?

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm honest. It was a DVD we received from a hotel of our stay - I've placed it into a DVD player and it works fine, it's just when it's in a Mac

Comment: Have you tried DVD Player in the Applications folder? What about [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/download-macosx.en_GB.html)?

Comment: As soon as I place the disk into my Mac it prompts me with a box saying that I have the option to eject or ignore or to open in finder - when I do open it in finder there's nothing

Comment: Just tried but got: supported disk not available as well as the same popular saying I've inserted a blank disk

Answer (score 1):

There's no such thing as a "Windows formatted" DVD. DVD and CD-ROMs have their own format which is supported by Windows, Mac, Linux and all sorts of appliances, media players, etc.

I will recommend testing:

1) Can the Mac play other DVDs than the problematic one?

2) Does the problematic DVD play on another PC?

If test 1 is negative, try to resolve the problem with the DVD drive on the Mac - for example cleaning the lens, etc. Maybe consider buying an external USB DVD-drive.

If test 2 is negative, try cleaning the DVD disc itself and check it for scratches, etc. It might not be possible to fully recover all the data from it.

If both tests are positive you might have a DVD that is in the process of being filled up with data - i.e. it is not finalized yet. You would then need to finalize the disc - most easily done using the original software you used for burning data to the disc.

Comment: It works in an Xbox and I can't test it in another computer or iMac as this is the only one with a DVD drive.

Comment: Do you have DVD player software installed on the Mac? - have you tried opening it and then insert the disc?

Comment: I have - no luck what so ever. I only get that it's an empty disk

Comment: So - does any other DVD work in the Mac? - I.e. can you play a commercial DVD movie for example?

Comment: I can view commercial ones. I haven't got another Mac I can place the disk into